# Can a mysql query done on information_schema crash tables?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

The software I'm using is using a MySQL server (version 5.0.52). 
Some of the databases are created dynamicaly, and I need to list the name of these (The criteria being databases containing 2 tables with different specific names). As such, I'm using a mysql query on information_schema to find what I need :

```
SELECT distinct T.table_schema  
FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T 
inner join information_schema.`TABLES` T2  
on T2.table_schema = T.table_schema  
where T.table_schema like 'myBase_%' 
and T.table_name like '%\_1' 
and T2.table_schema like 'myBase_%' 
and T2.table_name = 'myTable'
```

The MySQL service needs to be restarted manualy every 2 or 3 weeks because some tables appear to be crashed or locked. Error message from pid3306_crash.err (this is the first error, but once I have this line, this error appears for every table the software tries to query, giving me 5000 lines of "Cannot find the file"):

```
[ERROR] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Cannot find the file: '.\myBase_56320\petiquettes_k_1.frm' (Errcode: 22)
```

I enabled the full log for this mysql instance, and the only mysql query that could have access to this table is the one I quoted. There isn't any other query related to the first error also quoted above. 
So my question is : Is it possible that the query on information_schema is crashing my base, or should I look somewhere else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.0.52 is beyond obsolete -- almost 10 years old.  5.0 is long since deprecated, but meanwhile many, many bugs were fixed -- the last 5.0.x release was 5.0.96.

It is more likely for queries to information_schema to *reveal* problems related to data corruption (for example from failing hard drives or ransom memory errors) but it's not outside the bounds of reason for bugs to cause a crash.

So... it shouldn't, but it might.

The information_schema tables are not really tables -- they are SQL interfaces to internal server memory and disk structures.

Your next step (aside from moving to a more recent version of MySQL Server) is to reduce the demand on the information_schema code with temporary tables.

```
USE test; /* or some other schema, NOT information_schema */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ist1 AS SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ist2 AS SELECT * ist1;
```

Note that you should select only the necessary columns, since that may reduce the depth at which the server probes its internals to satisfy your query.

Now, you have two temp tables `ist1` and `ist2` with snapshots from information_schema.tables.  Rewrite your original query to use these.  They will persist until you disconnect from the server, then they'll be automatically dropped.

Comment: I know the version is really old, but because of license issues and compatibility issues with the working environment I can't upgrade without spending months on it, and I don't have the time to do it right now.
I'll try to look further into the log to try to explain it.

I'll try to use temporary tablse to see if it changes anything, thanks.